# Automic Integer Thread Clarification

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have the following code,

```
private final Map<String, AtomicInteger> wordCounter = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

AtomicInteger count = wordCounter.get(word);
if (count == null) {
    if ((count = wordCounter.putIfAbsent(word, new AtomicInteger(1))) == null) {
        continue;
    }
}
count.incrementAndGet();
```

I'm checking `count == null` in IF condition. As far as i know, operation in AutomicInteger is thread-safe.  Is it necessary to lock `count` instance using one of the locking mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code works without any additional locking, but it can be simplified to the following idiomatic form

```
// If word doesn't exist, create a new atomic integer, otherwise return the existing
wordCounter.computeIfAbsent(word, k -> new AtomicInteger(0))
    .incrementAndGet();  // increment it
```

Your code looks a bit like [double checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), in that `putIfAbsent()` is used after the null-check to avoid overwriting a value that was possibly put there by another thread. However that path creates an extra `AtomicInteger` which doesn't happen with DCL. The extra object probably wouldn't matter much, but it does make the solution a little less "pure".

Comment: thanks @Kayaman and i told the same but project mate is not agreed. :-(

Comment: @parrotjack about what? Your code works, but it does unnecessary extra work with `putIfAbsent`. The code I gave is a common pattern you can see in many places, and it's guaranteed to be thread-safe and atomic thanks to `ConcurrentHashMap` and `computeIfAbsent()`.

Comment: project mate feels the ```count``` instance needs to be synchronised. :-) However it's really great for your suggestion on ```computeIfAbsent()``` Thank you!

Comment: @parrotjack it's not even possible to synchronize on `count`, because it can be null. He might be thinking about double checked locking, but that doesn't fit into your original code.

Comment: @Kalyaman excellent, i will show this thread as a proof. :-)  Thanks a ton! :-)